# Spring security 4.0.0 in maven?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

There is [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle) about spring security 4.0.0  but in maven repository the latest version is 3.2.5. Where can I get the jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's said in the doc, you have to add a new repository in your pom.xml 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#maven-repositories

And then you'll find the dependency in 4.0.0 version

Answer (score 2):

Spring security **4.0.0.RELEASE** has not been released yet.

Use the following snippet for **4.0.0.RC1**:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies><repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

See here: http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

Answer (score 1):

The release version of Spring are hosted on Maven Central. However, if you want to use milestone or snapshot versions , then a custom Spring repository needs to be added to the pom
In your case 4.0 is in snapshot version
So First Add A New Custom Repository

```
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>repository.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
    <name>Spring Framework Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
```

Once You Define A Custom Repo Define Dependencies For Snapshot Build

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```